# Access all files from separate folders

Tags: php, content-management-system, shortcut

How can I access all the files from a folder for example:

I added my site files to a folder. In the root of the website, I have the folder that consist of my files, index.php and my theme menu. So my question is,

How can I access my files in that folder from a specific link in the menu?

I don't want them to be accessed like "`myste.com/sections/forum.php`" rather I need to know how to access them like "`mysite.com?page=forum`" or something like a CMS. I really appreciate if someone can help me with this. I havE been searching for solution but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: If you work with GET it probably will work like that if you write it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `mysite.com?page=forum` will run the index.php file in the mysite root folder.

So you need to write some code in the index.php file to redirect to the correct place, like

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET, $_GET['page'])) {
    // sanitize the $_GET contents
    switch ($_GET[['page']) {
        case 'form' :
           header( 'Location: sections/forum.php' );
           exit;
           break;
        case '...' :

        // etc etc
    }
} else {
    echo 'No $_GET';
}
```

Unfortunately it does not stop there, as its likely you will want to put other parameters on the querystring as well as the `page`. So now you have to decide what to do with those other parameters. Do you add them to the `header()` or do you store them somewhere else and make sure the rest of you app knows where to get them from.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET, $_GET['page'])) {
    // sanitize the $_GET contents
    $gets = $_GET;
    unset($gets['page'];
    $qs = '?' . implode('&',$gets);
    switch ($_GET[['page']) {
        case 'form' :
           header( 'Location: sections/forum.php' . $qs );
           exit;
           break;
        case '...' :
            // etc etc
       }
} else {
    echo 'No $_GET';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of ways to do this, but if i understood your question, one solution could be:

```
if (!empty($_GET["page"])) {
   switch ($_GET["page"]) {
        case "forum":
           include('section/forum.php');
           break;
        case "something_else":
           //include other file, or do whatever want
           break;
        default:
           //every else case 
           break;

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both, yea kinda work's but in the browser instead of showing mysite.com/index.php?page=forum shows mysite.com/sections/forum.php

Did I missed something ?

Thanks.